# ChartJS not rendering chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have the following AngularJS App:

```
angular.module("app-machines", ['ngFlatDatepicker'])
    .factory('MachinesService', ['$http', MachinesService])
    .controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'MachinesService', '$timeout', mainController])
    .directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) 
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                if (scope.$last === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Where here is what happens (pasting code would be too long).

- User has two controls (date from and date to) on a page, which upon changing fire an event which downloads data from a website (json).
- Afterwards I am simply storing the returned json into an object `$scope.machines`.
- Then I wait for `ng-repeat` on my webpage to finish rendering components (in my case for every item under `ng-repeat` I am creating a canvas where chart would be stored like following)

  ```
      <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="machine in machines" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
          <h1> {{ machine.name }}</h1>
          <canvas id="{{'myChart_' + $index}}" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
  ```

Once this has finished rendering, I am calling the following function

```
    $scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
        //you also get the actual event object
        //do stuff, execute functions -- whatever...

        var data = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",

                    // The properties below allow an array to be specified to change the value of the item at the given index
                    // String  or array - the bar color
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(100,220,220,0.2)",

                    // String or array - bar stroke color
                    borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

                    // Number or array - bar border width
                    borderWidth: 1,

                    // String or array - fill color when hovered
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",

                    // String or array - border color when hovered
                    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

                    // The actual data
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],

                    // String - If specified, binds the dataset to a certain y-axis. If not specified, the first y-axis is used.
                    yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                }
            ]
        };
        var options = {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }]
            }
        };

        for (var i = $scope.machines.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
            var ctx = $("#myChart_" + i);

            var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: data,
                options: options
            });

            myBarChart.update();

            console.log("processed " + i);
        }
    });
```

Here is the problem that occurs. The page is generated, I can see all my canvas with the charts, however the bars are only displayed for one chart only. The bars on the remaining charts have for unknown reason hidden bar. However I can still hover over them like this:

[image]

**FINAL**

So in the end the problem was caused by the fact, that all my charts were bound to the same data source (I had a static data source for now). Once I changed it to dynamic data source (all charts had their own dataset) it suddenly worked like a charm.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There are quite a lot of edge cases and intricities involved with interacting with Chart.js from within Angular. If you can, I would recommend using http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ which does it "the angular way".

Comment: thank you for the suggestion!